# Make certain nodes of group Private

Tags: organic-groups

How can i make certain nodes of group Private in a Public Group irrespective of content types.
So lets say I have a Public group X which has Page as a content type. So i have 10 as contents of groups which is public.So I have to make 2 contents of the group Private such that it is only available to the group members.

Tks in adv,
-Vil

Answer (score 0):

Enable Group Content Visibility field on Content Type. Using that field you can mark content under a group as public or private.

You need to enable OG ACCESS module to see those fields in admin/config/group/fields

Select the bundle as your content type in node section and select field Group Content Visibility from Fields Dropdown, click on Add field to add Group Content Visibility field for Content Type.